# Formatted .net web service (for .asmx solution)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, web-services, asmx

I have searched this but really I couldn't find the exact answer for `.asmx` solution. How can I create a .Net web service that is formatted as seen below? Also It will be connected with a database.

```
<Books>
    <Book BookID="1" BookName="BookName1" Page="100"/>
    <Book BookID="2" BookName="BookName1" Page="200"/>
    <Book BookID="3" BookName="BookName1" Page="300"/>
</Books>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "formatted"?

Comment: I mean looks like the code above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `WCF` with `BasicHttpBinding` for simulating `.asmx` web services.

you can use :

```
[WebMethod] 
public XmlDocument YourMethod() 
{  
}
```

and you can have a look to this link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mpowell/archive/2004/05/12/130637.aspx

Comment: @JohnSaunders You are right it's a legacy technology but I have to use a legacy technology for now, so He gave a solution about my want. Thank you also.

Comment: @David: if you required an ASMX solution, then you should have said so in your question.

Comment: I will remove the downvote, but I can't do that until the question is edited. I suggest you remove the part about WCF, now that the OP has stated that he requires an ASMX solution.

Comment: @David: thanks, but I meant that Kerezo needs to edit his answer in order for me to reverse the downvote.

Comment: Why I should Edit my answer?some one like to use legacy technology.some one like you in SO downvote by personal taste not scientific taste

Answer (score 0):

I gather from your post that you're using WCF.  (I'd recommend switching to MVC or "Web API", as that makes this kind of thing a lot easier.)  Using WCF though, you can set the body style to "bare" in the operation contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Books GetBooks();
```

I imagine you already have the entity set up something like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Book
{
    [DataMember]
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String BookName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Page { get; set; }
}
```

Using that contract should cause the service to return XML as you specified, as defined in the data contract, without the soap wrapper.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying that for a new WCF project. Is it possible to create with XML Web Service? I mean ".asmx"?

Comment: Well, I think the .asmx service always wraps the result in SOAP.  If you don't mind that, you can always just return your XML as you like by setting the return time to "string" or the Linq "XElement".  See this link for more info:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx